# Issue with passing variables to view_cell function in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever I try
`<?= view_cell('SearchCell::mysearch', ['key'=> 123]) ?>`

This throws an error in

```
  print_r($param);
}


Error: Too few arguments passed

However I tried changing namespace, function defination to camelCase but still not working.
```